# How to put a variable name in for loop?

Tags: php, codeigniter, for-loop

I got value using this:

```
        $count = <?php  $details->shop_image_count; ?>
```

I want to use this `$count` in my `for loop`, but I am not getting the value of count

```
         <?php 
           for($i=1;$i<($count);$i++){                  
                  echo '<li data-target="#shopCarousel" data-slide-to="' . $i . '"></li>';                  
             }
         ?>
```

Comment: Thank u very much all of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like this

```
$count = $details->shop_image_count;
```

instead of

```
$count = <? echo $details->shop_image_count;?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$count = $details->shop_image_count;
```

Insted of this

```
$count = <? echo $details->shop_image_count;?>
```

And your for loop

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<$count; $i++){
   echo '<li data-target="#shopCarousel" data-slide-to="'.$i.'"></li>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to close php in the loop. Make your code more readable and maintainable, like below:

```
<?php  
   for ($i = 1; $i <= $details->shop_image_count; $i++)
      echo '<li data-target="#shopCarousel" data-slide-to="' . $i . '"></li>';
?>
```

Further, you start with 1, so you want to loop while $i **<=** $details->shop_image_count

Answer (score 1):

`$count = <? echo $details->shop_image_count;?>` is not correct syntax.

Try

```
<?php
    $count = $details->shop_image_count;  
    for($i=1; $i<($count); $i++)
    {
?>
        <li data-target="#shopCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i;?>"></li>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = $details->shop_image_count;
```

Then use this method for better application

```
     for($i=1;$i<(intval($count));$i++){
          ?>
       <li data-target="#shopCarousel" data-slide-to="<? echo $i?>"></li>
          <?php
          }
          ?>
```